# AddObserver on UILabel not working

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am trying to get notifications whenever the text changes in my UILabel so that I can resize it to fit the new text. Here is my code:

```
public class MessageContainer : UILabel
{
    private readonly int _width;

    public MessageContainer(int width)
    {
        _width = width;
        TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        Font = UIFont.PreferredTitle1;
        TextColor = UIColor.White;
        Lines = 999;

        this.AddObserver("text", Foundation.NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial | Foundation.NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, TextChanged);
    }

    private void TextChanged(Foundation.NSObservedChange change)
    {
        var s = change.NewValue as Foundation.NSString;

        if (s != null) // s is always null here
        {
            var size = s.StringSize(UIFont.PreferredTitle1, new CGSize(_width - 20, 999), UILineBreakMode.CharacterWrap);
            this.ResizeFrame(size.Width, size.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

My `TextChanged` function gets called, but `change.NewValue` is always null. I am using Xamarin.iOS, but I'm sure the answer is the same in Objective-C or Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple subclass for UILabel with a delegate to tell you when the text changes:

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {
    var delegate: MyLabelDelegate?
    override var text: String {
        willSet(string) {
            delegate?.willSet(self, text: string)
        }
    }
}

protocol MyLabelDelegate {
    func willSet(_ label: MyLabel, text: String)
}
```

---

I did this on my phone, so it’s not tested, but it should work.

Comment: This worked. I didn't even know I can override properties!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use key-value observing for this; instead, you would need to subclass UILabel and detect when the text is set.

However, I'm a little surprised that you think you need this, since how can you *not* know when a label's text changes? The only way that can happen is that *you* changed it. Moreover, UILabel is self-resizing under autolayout, so it's hard to see what the problem is supposed to be. It "just works" the way you want it to.

Comment: I'm using MvvmCross, the code that changes the text is not even in the iOS project. And the UILabel is in a cell of a UITableView.

I added the UILabel to the view programmatically (I don't use storyboards) and it doesn't self-resize...is there a way to make it self-resize?

Comment: If you position it using autolayout constraints, it will become self-resizing. Otherwise, just send `sizeToFit` to it. Either way, you are way over-thinking this (I think).